# Extracting decimal numbers from a string

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a string such as `"3.1 ml"` or `"abc 3.1 xywazw"`

I'd like to extract `"3.1"` from this string. I have found many questions on stackoverflow about the extraction of numbers from a character string, but no solution works for the case of decimal numbers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This approach makes the decimal point and decimal fraction optional and allows multiple numbers to be extracted:

```
str <- " test 3.1 test 5"
as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(str,
                             gregexpr("[-]{0,1}[[:digit:]]+\\.{0,1}[[:digit:]]*",str))
          )      )
#[1] 3.1 5.0
```

The concern about negative numbers can be address with optional perl style look-ahead:

```
 str <- " test -4.5 3.1 test 5"
    as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(str,gregexpr("(?>-)*[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*",str, perl=TRUE))))

#[1] -4.5  3.1  5.0
```

The regex-logic in the following version mandates spaces separating numeric from text:

```
str <- " test 3.1 test 5  another test -3.3 and a negative case -3..3"
as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(str,
                             gregexpr("[ ][-]{0,1}[[:digit:]]+\\.{0,1}[[:digit:]]*[ ]",str)) ))
```

The variant answers to this question highlight the difficulties in making a parser using regex logic.

Comment: Mmm I have found a "bug" today: it drops the minus sign of negative numbers

Comment: Put a 'minus' next to the [:digit:]

Comment: The problem with the `*` quantifier for the decimal point is the potential to match intervals expressed as `1..2` or `2...3` etc. See @Wojciech Sobala's solution with the optional quantifier (`?`).

Comment: If you want to prevent double periods then could also change `*` to `{0,1}`

Answer (score 20):

Use the `stringr` library:

```
x<-"abc 3.1 xywazw"
str_extract(x, "\\d+\\.*\\d*")
[1] "3.1"
```

Comment: Possibly use `"\\d+\\.\\d+"`

Comment: Thank you. @RicardoSaporta is right. This would not work for `13.1` for instance.

Comment: And neither would work for "10". I don't think the "+" is the right repetition quantifier to use for the second or third expressions.

Comment: Right @DWin. `str_extract(x, "\\d+\\.*\\d*")` is better.

Comment: Yes @Stephane, updated the answer to reflect this as it's more generalizeable.

Comment: Hello tcash21. Do you know how to do to keep the minus sign of negative values ?

Comment: I'm using `str_extract(string, "\\-*\\d+\\.*\\d*")`, do you think it is correct ? (it's new hence not very experimented so far)

Comment: Try `str_extract(x, "-*\\d+\\.*\\d*")`

Answer (score 8):

Regular expression for floating point number from http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html with minor adjustment to work in R.

```
s <- "1e-6 dkel"
regmatches(s,gregexpr("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?",s)) 
> [[1]]
> [1] "1e-6"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions :

```
> str <- " test 3.1 test"
> as.numeric(regmatches(str,regexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+",str)))
[1] 3.1
```

`regexpr`returns the start position and length of the matched string. `regmatches`returns the matches. You can then convert it to a number.

Comment: My upvote was locked in. I tried to reverse it when I realized the "." was being used inappropriately. It needs to be escaped. Perhaps you can fix that error and the upvote will then be earned.

Comment: @DWin If you input the text " test 3p1 test" for instance, it is not matched. So I am not sure the "." needs to be escaped here.

Comment: "3p1" is matched, but then converted to NA by `as.numeric`.

Comment: Please forgive my silly mistake ... I edited my answer. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

```r
readr::parse_number(c("abc 3.1 xywazw", "-3.1 ml", "1,234.56"))
# [1]    3.10   -3.10 1234.56
```

Comment: If there is more than one number within a string this only extracts the first instance.