# Extract decimal values without leading zero from a string in R

Tags: r

All, I am trying to extract values from text strings and I found the thread: [Extracting decimal numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252663/extracting-decimal-numbers-from-a-string). However, the cases I am encountering are the numbers without a leading zero and the solution will drop the decimal point. For example:

```
> str <- "the value is .55"
> as.numeric(str_extract(str, "\\d+\\.*\\d*"))
[1] 55
```

I am hoping to recover the 0.55 value instead of 55 and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `as.numeric(str_extract(str, "(\\d+)?\\.\\d*"))`

Comment: If you don't have `0.**` you have to insert it, which suggests a kind of test for \\. with gsub(.

Comment: You can also do `readr::parse_number(str)`

Comment: `gsub('\\.', '0\\.', str)` . [1] "the value is 0.55" which would be useful if all your cases were consistent.

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub('.*(\\.)', '\\1', str))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `str_extract_all` if you have more than one value per string. The key is switching the `+` (one or more) with a `*` (zero or more) for the integer part.

```
str <- "the value is .55 or 0.9 and 89"
```

```
library(stringr)

as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(str, "\\d*\\.*\\d+")))
[1]  0.55  0.90 89.00
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R we can do

```
> x <- 'the value is .55 or 0.9 and 89'
> x1 <- "the value is .55"
> f <- \(x) as.numeric(el(regmatches(x, gregexpr('[0|\\.]?\\d+\\.?\\d+', x))))
> f(x)
[1]  0.55  0.90 89.00
> f(x1)
[1] 0.55
```

Comment: A little expansion on `el`'s use here likely quite useful to those of us following along ...

Comment: @chris `el(x)` is very similar to `x[[1]]` but saves one byte.

Comment: But, why is the expansion of `object[i][[i]]` (typically replaceable by `object[[i]]`) more serviceable here? Not wishing to annoy, just a very 'unique' expression within the context of many regex question responses.

Comment: @Chris Good question (but it's rather `object[where][[1L]]` than `object[i][[i]]`.). Documentation says _"el(object, i) is equivalent to object[i][[1]] (and should typically be replaceable by object[[i]])."_ The reason why `el(1)`, i.e. `where` is missing, actually doesn't yield an error may lie somewhere in the C source code of the bracket function [`\`[\`()`](https://github.com/search?q=SEXP%20attribute_hidden%20do_subset+repo:wch/r-source&type=Code).

Comment: +1, yes, my above notation is wrong, not [[i]] but [[1'L']]. Closer read required. So, what data would force `where` missing to demonstrate this?, as neither `x` nor `x1` above appear to, unless I've misinterpretted and`object[where}[[1L]]` means no leading `0.`, and missing is in `x`.

Comment: @Chris Sorry my mind was somewhere deep in the source code, you can literally replace to `f <- \(x) as.numeric(regmatches(x, gregexpr('[0|\\.]?\\d+\\.?\\d+', x))[[1L]])`. I just like `el(x)` better than `x[[1L]]` because it's more elegant. Your question is about why the former might be better than the latter I cannot answer because I currently don't understand why `el(1)` doesn't throw an `Error: object 'where' not found`.

Comment: @Chris Your (or rather my) question has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76766868/6574038) satisfactorily. While `el(c(1, 2))` gives 1, `el(c(1, 2), 2)` yields 2. In the first case where`where=` is missing, [lazy evaluation](https://bookdown.dongzhuoer.com/hadley/adv-r/lazy-evaluation.html) prevents occurrence of an error.