# Why doesn't missing parameter in function using the bracket function throw error?

Tags: r, syntax

In

```
> f <- function(x, y) {
+   x[y]
+ }
> f(1)
[1] 1
```

why doesn't this throw an

```
Error: object 'y' not found
```

?

Note, that this is equivalent to

```
> f <- function(x, y) {
+     `[`(x, y)
+ }
```

Comment: Looks like it's never evaluated and therefore `1[]` is just `1`

Comment: @thelatemail Indeed, `identical(1, 1[])` is `TRUE`, but `1[foo]` throws `Error: object 'foo' not found`.

Answer (score 1):

When you type `` ?`[` ``, you will see the statement about missing (empty) indices

> An empty index selects all values: this is most often used to replace
> all the entries but keep the attributes.

Thus, if `y` is missing in the call of `f`, the code will be parsed as `x[]`, which is the case described in its help manual.

---

Also, thanks for @Roland's comments:z

> The explanation is missing this part: ["However, missingness can be
> passed on from function to function, for using a formal argument as an
> actual argument in a function call does not count as evaluation."](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Missingness)

Comment: I already suspected some useful magic in the C code of the bracket function, and why doesn't the parser need y, because it's lazy evaluation, right, bracket doesn't need it!

Comment: The explanation is missing this part: ["However, missingness can be passed on from function to function, for using a formal argument as an actual argument in a function call does not count as evaluation."](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Missingness)

Comment: @jay.sf probably you can refer to Roland's comment.